# iis 7 worker process memory leaks / hangs

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, .net, debugging, memory-leak

From my diagnosis the worker process stops responding randomly, the server becomes very slow with **100% cpu utilization**. I'm not certain but I think its because of w3wp.exe process which is my app pool.

At this time, **no websites respond**, I have to restart IIS in order to make it work. Mostly the IIS restart / MSSQL restart does not work (error stating services are not responding) and I have to **restart the entire server**.

I don't understand if this is a Memory Leak / Crash / IIS Hang issue. I have installed DebugDiag from Microsoft.com & created dump files however unable to understand what the analysis results are that mention max time consuming threads etc.

> Server -
>   Windows Server 2008 SP2
>   MS Sql Server 2008
>   IIS 7

I recently upgraded from windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 / mssql 2005 to mssql 2008 and `this issue was persisting in the old server as well`, so I'm certain its one of my applications being mischievous.

Thank you so much for reading through my issue. You help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about IIS7 is that you can use Failed Request Tracing and Runtime Service Control API (RSCA).

At the top level, go to the worker processes icon, then drill into your worker process and see which page is running the longest.  That's likely the cause.  Once you've narrowed down to the appropriate page,  then turn on Failed Request Tracing in IIS7 at the site level.  Set it for just the bad page.  Once you've captured a page running poorly, the .xml results can hopefully help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response Scott. But this issue occurs randomly, otherwise the pages run pretty smooth all the time. I'm gonna try and check your recommendation

Comment: The intermittent issues are the most difficult.  With IIS7, at least you can look at it in real-time when it occurs.